# How to trig a function from Iframe to his parent ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I have a web page loading a iframe (inside a modal Fancybox) and this iframe contains a form with 2 pages. 
I want this iframe content to ask the parent to trig a function (so the modal can be resized when the 2nd page of the form is shown)

```
    $.fancybox.update();
```

When executed in the iframe, it doesn't work because it needs to be in parent context. So far, I managed to do it with binding a click on the "next page" button inside the iFrame.

```
    $('body iframe').contents().find('.goToPage2').bind('click', function (e) {               
            $.fancybox.update();
    });
```

This was working.

But now, I have to do it without waiting for a click (it has to happen after getting an ajax response). So I tried to bind a "show" action, and make a div appear with after(), but it didn't work.

```
    $('body iframe').contents().find('#page2').bind('show', function (e) {               
            $.fancybox.update();                
        });
```

I also tried to reach the parent directly from the iframe but with no luck in my case (fancybox) :

```
    $('#page2', window.parent.document).fancybox.update();
```

If anyone can explain how I can achieve this, I will be grateful :-)

Comment: change `$('#page2', window.parent.document).fancybox` to `window.parent.$.fancybox` - or just `parent.$.fancybox` - because window.parent is the windows parent "window" object, on which the parent windows $ object resides, which has the `fancybox` object

Comment: have you tried "window.top" to get the parent window object from inside iframe?

Comment: Jaromanda X solution worked ! You can post it as the answer ;-)